# Parameter passing between scripts in HP UFT

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I am storing a value in an Environment variable in one of my script, now i want to use that value as input parameter for another script and trigger that script, is there any way for that ?

Comment: I am new to QTP and this is first time that i am trying to integrate two scripts.

Comment: How you are calling another script . If we going to use external action then we can pass

Comment: You can pass its value as you do for normal variables.... read the environment value into some variable and pass it to the method/function/script you intend to trigger. Otherwise, give some base snippet you tried, so that we can help you further.....

Answer (score 0):

If you call an external action, the environment variables are passed to the action you are calling.  I believe that you will need to set up the same environment variable names that you wish to use in the external action in order to do this though.

For example: I've got an action that sets a variable and then passes control to an external action:

```
Environment("accessToken") = "ABCDEFG"
RunAction "JSON-G3DB Comparison_Section [JSON Data Validation_Section]", oneIteration
```

The *JSON Data Validation_Section* will be able to access the environment variables (accessToken will equal "ABCDEFG") -- as long as they exist in **both** actions' environment declarations.